# How can i resolve Empty string supplied as input in DOMDocument::loadXML() in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, adminhtml, phtml, dom

when I compile my code I have this kind of error accurse

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in /mnt/data/home/cloudwaysapps.com/ssucdkafzj/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di
  /Code/Scanner/ServiceDataAttributesScanner.php on line 24
```

[image]

Comment: If answer help, upvote and accept as solution. so it help other in community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the given `extension_attribute.xml` and remove the starting space into that one

```
like :


<?xml version="1.0"?>
```